# redmine API: cannot GET issues.json with curl

Tags: curl, redmine, redmine-api

When I issue the following command, I got a  HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized error:

```
curl -v -XGET -u admin:admin http://my_projects.heroku.com/projects/PROJECT_NAME/issues.json
```

Any idea ?

**UPDATE**

```
curl -v -XGET http://my_projects.heroku.com/news.json
curl -v -XGET http://my_projects.heroku.com/projects.json
```

are working fine (I mean, I do not have 401 error but obviously my private projects is not listed).
Seems that the permissions of my issues are not correctly set...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found the pb ! I'm new to Redmine and did not enable the web services.